# Python: Use regex to extract a column of a file

Tags: python, regex

I am currently extracting columns in a file by using awk in os.system():

```
os.system("awk '{print $'%i'}' < infile > outfile"%some_column)
np.loadtxt('outfile')
```

Is there an equivalent way to accomplish this using regex?

Thanks.

Edit: I want to clarify that I am looking for the most optimal way to extract specific columns of large files.

Comment: Use `csv` library if you work with CSV.

Comment: you could do something simple like [this](https://regex101.com/r/n9nELi/1).  Add more commas before and after to select your column. If you have a big file you may want to just use the ```csv``` module.

Comment: For csv, you can also use pandas' `csv_read` and `loc` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your data delimiters are, regex is probably overkill for this. If the delimiters are simple (whitespace or a specific character/string), you can separate columns simply by using the [`string.split` method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Here is an example program to explain how this might work:

```python
column = 0  # First column
with open("data.txt") as file:
  data = file.readlines()
columns = list(map(lambda x: x.strip().split()[column], data))
```

To break this down:

```python
column = 0
# Read a file named "data.txt" into an array of lines
with open("data.txt") as file:
  data = file.readlines()
# This is where we will store the columns as we extract them
columns = []
# Iterate over each line in the file
for line in data:
  # Strip the whitespace (including the trailing newline character) from the
  # start and end of the string
  line = line.strip()
  # Split the line, using the standard delimiter (arbitrary number of
  # whitespace characters)
  line = line.split()
  # Extract the column data from the desired index and store it in our list
  columns.append(line[column])
# columns now holds a list of strings extracted from that column
```

Comment: Isn't this less efficient for large files though?

Comment: It is true that reading the whole file at once is a bad idea if you might operate on large files. I interpreted your question as being about how to extract a column, not how to optimally read from a file, so that is what my example code is meant to show. If I were writing a full-fledged program, I would also not hardcode the column index or the data file path.